# Getting the error while running Cucumber TestNG with Java through eclipse

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng-eclipse, selenium-extent-report

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> org/testng/remote/RemoteTestNG has been compiled by a more recent
> version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of
> the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Tried downgrading and upgrading the TestNG version. The Java version is 1.8. TestNG - 6.14.3 Eclipse: 2023.09, Cucumber 6.19.3

I can trigger if I change the java version in build path to Java-SE11. But I think due to this Spark report and PDF report are not getting generated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. Changed the Java version to 1.11 in pom.xml and it works fine now. Able to generate extent html and pdf report both.